# Application of first isomorphism theorem

Tags: group-theory

Let $G$ and $K$ be groups and let $G\times K$ be the direct product of these two groups. Find a normal subgroup $N$ such that $(G\times K)/N\cong G.$

I think I need to use the first isomorphisms theorem, stating that if $\varphi \colon G\rightarrow H$ is a homomorphism then $G/\ker(\varphi)\cong$ im$(\varphi).$

I'm don't really know where to go from this point though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can define $\phi:G\times K\to G\;,\;\;\phi(g,k):=g\;$ . This is homomorphism surjective, and check that $$\ker\phi=\{1\}\times K=N$$

and now use first isomorphism theorem

Answer (score 4):

Consider the canonical projection $G \times K \to G$.

Prove that this is a surjective homomorphism and compute its kernel.